# How to set the proguard settings with regard to the new Object { } Construct?

Tags: java, android, object, proguard

I have below code in my android app:

```
    Object obj = new Object() {
        Object categories = myGame.menu.categoryList;
    };
    String xmlStr = Mustache.compiler().compile(templateStr).execute(obj);
```

It works if no proguard is applied. While if proguard is applied, it will get NPE error when opening the app. After investigating, the "Object categories" must be kept. But I googled everywhere, still not sure how to make "Object categories" not to be obsfucated so the name unchanged...

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Get rid of the anonymous inner class. Create a regular Java class with a regular data member named `categories`, and use that with Mustache.

Step #2: Configure ProGuard to keep your Java class.